# Are filler chapters/episodes unnecessary?

Tags: plot, character-development, planning, chapters, relationships

I was considering the use of filler chapters in my story, to flesh out the character's problems and daily life. These don't necessary progress the plot, but they do help the characters' relationships with each other to grow and develop and be useful for the plot. However, it seems like a bad idea as the more progressive it is, the better the story. I'd also have to consider the pacing, as the existence of filler chapters seems to make it looks slow.

Comment: If you have a quota to reach (e.g. 13 episodes to produce but only content for 12), then filler may be "necessary". But I don't think plot progression is the only criterion for whether something is or is not filler.

Comment: I basically need to find ways to flesh out the characters, without forcing it into everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've correctly identified that you shouldn't be using "filler" chapters to bulk something out, and I sympathise that you don't want to force the pace/action into the scenes just to fulfil the requirement.

There's not an easy answer to this - some readers may get bored if nothing "is happening", but you also don't want to force this character building/bonding into other scenes and dilute them too much.

Is there no suitable "downtime" between action (generally you write the interesting bits, then dodge the rest) where this could fit better?  Remember that some slower paced action amongst the rest can provide the reader with a nice little break, and reset their appetite for more action - provided it doesn't last too long.

What is the "dramatic question" for these scenes?  Is there any tension that you could be building with these chapters?

Most fundamentally of all, are these "filler" chapters enjoyable to read?  Personally, I'm quite happy to read something slower if I like the characters, what they're talking about is interesting, and the piece is well written.

Comment: I see. Though there are downtime in the chapters from its serious progressive plot, Im not sure whether to fit them. Besides, the plot kept them busy and prevents them from normal human experience and life. Though i will think of a possibility

Answer (score 1):

You have about 1/4 of the story (Act I), upfront, in which the audience is *expecting* you to introduce and flesh out the personalities of the characters. This is when the audience will forgive some stalls and such. There is often some sort of action in the middle of Act I, the "inciting incident" or crisis that is going to begin the plot, but even that doesn't mean the end of fleshing out the characters. The hero(es) will not be forced out of their "normal world" until the end of Act I, which is when the inciting incident or crisis has proven intractable to address and dismiss as a "normal" problem they could handle while continuing their normal life.

So to start, I suspect you are starting your action too early, jumping into it before you have told us who is who, and letting us in on a glimpse of their early life.

After that, in Act IIa and IIb, action should rise and fall; successes and failures, battles and rest. It is in-between the battles that you can further advance the personal plots and such for the characters.

In a typical movie, we see this character development in the lulls between the action; quiet talk during travel, during rest, during eating. That is how the "B" story (usually a romance) develops; we alternate between the "A" story (action and suspense) and the "B" story (the transition breaks between action scenes, these are more reflective, conversational, and often tender or character revealing).

Even most action movies are not non-stop action. But if you are writing wall-to-wall action, then don't worry about character development. The audience is absorbed in the action.